# Is it possible to shorten a unix terminal command to a shorter one?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Let's say I have this command:

```
/sbin/ifconfig|grep inet|head -1|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk '{print $3}'
```

Is it possible to shorten this to let's say writing `host` in the command line?

Comment: "host" is already occupied, but sure, by editing your `~/.bashrc` search for it on askubuntu should give you plenty of results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create shell alias, which is exactly what you need:

```
$ alias mycmd="/sbin/ifconfig|grep inet|head -1|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk '{print $3}'"
```

You probably want to have above alias permanent. To achieve this, add the above alias command to the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: It will likely be necessary to escape the `$` in the awk field i.e. `awk '{print \$3}'"` to prevent the shell from expanding it during alias creation